# can I set proxy to AWS S3 static web hosting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

first of all I'm sorry for my bad english.

I need to set proxy on my static web hosting using s3.

for example,

s3 static web hosting sample is http://www.sample-site.com

http://www.sample-site.com/items/1 => reverse proxy on http://www.TEST.com

like this.

which means, when client access using http://www.TEST.com, I want to http://www.sample-site.com/items/1

**I don't know it is possible or not and if possible, how can i set it on S3?**

Comment: Yes s3 static host support routing rule. you can check out below docs may be it will helpful :- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax

Comment: @JogendraKumar that's redirection, not reverse proxying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged your question with nginx, I assume you are running an EC2 instance with nginx installed, and you want to proxy few of your static assets hosted on an S3 bucket.

If that is the case, you are headed in the right direction by enabling S3 static website on your bucket.

You need to follow the nginx reverse proxy guide to achieve your outcome.

You can find more information on nginx reverse proxy here:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Running in ec2 instance will be my last solution.
I want to find out is it possible WITHOUT any ec2 instance. Using s3 static web hosting can set proxy or not.
Thanks again.